# Add to cart should update the Side Bar

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I designed a custom product detail page for variable product where I give option to user where he/she can select each variation and its quantity and then can add it to cart on single click multiple variation to cart. I achieved this functionality but as it is ajax process when product is added to cart it doesn't reflect in side cart(woolentor sidecart) without page reload.

Note : When I reload page products appears in side cart but I want to achieve it without page reload.

here is my code :

```
global $product; 
        $product_id  = $product->get_id();
        
       if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
           echo "<div class='nav_opt_cont'>";
            foreach($variations as $variation) {
//           echo "<pre>";  
//              var_dump($variation);
             echo "<div class='nav_var_option'>
                  <h4 class='nav_text' data_pid='".$product_id."' nav-var='".$variation["variation_id"]."'>".$variation["attributes"]["attribute_pa_size"]."</h4>
                  <p class='nav_desc'>".$variation["variation_description"]."</p>
             </div>";
                 }
           echo "</div><div class='nav_cta_cont'>";
           foreach($variations as $variation) {
             echo "<div class='nav_cta'  data_var='".$variation["variation_id"]."' style='display:none;'>
             <label>".$variation["attributes"]["attribute_pa_size"]."</label>
            <input type='number' class='input-text qty text' name='quantity' value='1' title='Qty' size='4' min='1' max='' step='1' placeholder='' inputmode='numeric' autocomplete='off'>
            <span class='nav_close'> x </span>
             </div>";
                 }
           echo "</div>
           <div class='nav_action'><button class='nav_var_add_to_cart'>Add to cart</button> </div>";
             }
```

Ajax Call

```
jQuery('body').on('click','.nav_var_add_to_cart', function(){
             var resp = "a";
             jQuery(".nav_var_option.active").each(function(i , obj) {
                
            let product_id =  jQuery(obj).find('.nav_text').attr('data_pid'); 
            let var_id = jQuery(obj).find('.nav_text').attr('nav-var');
            let qty = jQuery("[data_var="+var_id+"]").find('.qty').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                  type : "post", 
                  async: false,
                  cache: false,
                  timeout: 30000,
                  url : '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php");  ?>',
                  data : {
                    action: "nav_add_to_cart", 
                    product_id : product_id, 
                    variation_id : var_id,
                    nav_quantity : qty
                        },
                    fail: function(){
                    alert("error");
                    return true;
                  },
            success: function(response) { 
                resp = response;
                console.log(response);
               
            }
             
         
      });
    
}); 
        console.log(resp);
        if(resp == "success"){
          alert("added to cart"); 
          
        }
    
        });
```

PHP Function :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nav_add_to_cart', 'nav_add_to_cart'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nav_add_to_cart', 'nav_add_to_cart');          
function nav_add_to_cart() {  
    $product_id = (int) $_REQUEST['product_id'];
    $quantity = $_REQUEST['nav_quantity'];
    $variation_id =  (int) $_REQUEST['variation_id'];
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id); 
    if (WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) { 
     
          echo "success";
            } else { 
              echo "Error";  
            }
            wp_die();
        }
```

[VISUAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT2OJ.png)

I tried to find any available hook for this but could'nt find it . anyone here to help?

Comment: I guess this is not the event that the plugin itself uses - nav_add_to_cart ? You need to hook to the plugin event or trigger update on the even to update your content.

Comment: I found the solution I used woocommerce refresh fragments after ajax response . That helped me .